# Exe4j, windows service, handle shutdown event

Tags: windows, service, exe4j

I have java program, running as a Windows Service with exe4j. Is there any way to handle shutdown event from exe4j wrapper? I want clean up (close database connection, stop running threads  etc.) before service is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running. The current runtime can be obtained from the getRuntime method. One can register itself shutdown hook:

java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)